# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 fails to start after installing XAMPP/MAMP on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, apache-http-server, mysql, sql-server, ssms

When I try to launch SQL Server Management Studio 18, I get a Windows chime and no other response or error messages. Initially, after installing SSMS 18 and SQL Server 17, both worked fine for a day until I installed XAMPP when the issues started.

The following did not work:

- Repairing installation
- Uninstalling & reinstalling
- Deleting 18.0 (version) folders from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server using Regedit.exe

I eventually got it working again after uninstalling XAMPP, then uninstalling and reinstalling SSMS and SQL Server, but as soon as I installed MAMP as an alternative the same problem arose again.

The state of the MAMP/XAMPP server processes seems to have no influence on the problem. It is purely related to the fact that local server environment was installed. Surely if this is due to a port or a .NET issue, there should give me an appropriate error msg instead of the non-descript chime.

Any help will be appreciated as I have trawled the forums to no avail and need to host a testing environment on my machine.

**EDIT:**
I found the following, which I suspect relates to the same problem:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37502512-ssms2018-installed-but-will-not-run

This has supposedly been fixed in SSMS 18.1. I added the interim Microsoft workaround for SSMS 18.0 in the answer below.

Comment: Edit your question with enough information to determine if you have a port configuration issue or not.

Comment: I can't get into SSMS to access the port configuration. Is there a way to do it through the command line? I tried changing the default ports on XAMPP/MAMP and it had no effect.

Comment: XAMPP and MAMP have little to do with the .NET Framework.  I am trying to understand what conflict you think might exist with it?

Comment: You don't know what port you configured your SQL Server to run on?  We need that information in order to answer your question.

Comment: The problem started twice after installing a local server environment. A .NET version issue was raised as a potential problem on another thread I found. I'm not suggesting they are related. Do you maybe have any advice on resolving a port issue without using SSMS? I'm new to SQL, so it might well be the case, but most forums point to using SSMS to fix it and I can't access it. As I said in the question, changing the port settings on MAMP/XAMPP had no effect.

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared your research

Comment: Using SQL Server Configuration Manager, I found all ports were set to dynamic (blank?) with TCP/IP disabled. I enabled TCP/IP, but still had no luck getting past the chime. I eventually managed to get everything to run by uninstalling MAMP, SQL Server and SSMS. And reinstalling SQL Server and SSMS, I then confirmed it to launch correctly and kept SSMS running while installing MAMP. After that everything worked as advertised. As this is far from a technically satisfying answer, I will leave it open until I run into this issue again or find a better way to approach it.

Comment: You should submit an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in SSMS 18.0. Microsoft recommends the
following:

> The issue (in .NET) has been investigated and understood.
>   The recommended workaround, in the interim, is:
>   1) Close all instances of SSMS
>   2) Edit ssms.exe.config
>   3) Remove the line that has the following text (should be line 38): > NgenBind_OptimizeNonGac enabled=“1”
>
> That’s the same change that will be in the next release of SSMS 18.x 
>   **THIS IS THE DEFINITIVE SOLUTION FROM MICROSOFT, AND IS THE TRUE
>   ANSWER.**

It's been added to the release notes of SSMS 18.0.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/76236e43-dc82-4586-bf7f-b01ff6374462/ssms2018-installed-but-will-not-run?forum=sqltools

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server Configuration Manager, I found all ports were set to dynamic (blank) with TCP/IP disabled. I enabled TCP/IP, but still had no luck getting past the chime.

I eventually managed to get everything to run by uninstalling MAMP, SQL Server and SSMS. After reinstalling SQL Server and SSMS, I then confirmed it to launch correctly and kept SSMS running while installing MAMP. After that everything worked as advertised.