# Issue with Microsoft SQL server management studio 2019

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql, xampp, sql-management-studio

When i installed Microsoft SQL server management studio it runs properly with no issue but i have installed XAMPP for mysql on my system but when i run it afterwards SQL server does not working.
does not work.
Microsoft SQL server management studio opens for a second and get automatically closed.Reinstalling Microsoft SQL server management studio  runs it again but same thing happens after someday.
I don't know whether is it a problem with XAMPP or its maybe some other issue but i m not  able to solve this problem please help me with it.
Software's :
 Microsoft SQL server management studio 2019
 XAMPP version 7.3.3
OS :
Windows 8.1

Comment: SSMS is for SQL server and XAMPP have a MySQL database. not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I know that but I m using both of them for different purposes and I got the issue I specified

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 fails to start after installing XAMPP/MAMP on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1439835/microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-18-fails-to-start-after-installing-xampp)